# How to differentiate the fill color and the border color in graphics?

Tags: python

In python, I want to differentiate the color to fill and the color of the frame and get the following plot: [screenshot of plot with several circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyxBn.png)

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='x y
A 2
B 2.5
C 1.6')
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(shape=21, colour="black", fill="yellow", size=15)
```

I tried `matplotlib`, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I actually not sure if matplotlib have this option. You could build your own graph with tkinter canvas and you had a lot of option to configure, but you would need to do the math and the functions for yourself.

Comment: It would depend completely on the plotting / graphics module being used.

Comment: I haven't find anything similar to ggplot in python. I just got back to R to make implementations.